# Angular 1 application not letting me add overflow-y auto property to drag items correctly

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, angularjs

I have an angular 1 application that uses the angular dragdrop library.

This is the container of the cards that can be dragged in the view:

```
<div class="thumbnail stage" data-drop="true" ng-model="column.items" data-jqyoui-options="column.options" jqyoui-droppable="{multiple:true, onDrop: 'onDropCard($event, $ui)'}" data-column-index3="{{column}}">
                            <div class="caption">
```

And these are the draggable items:

```
 <div ng-repeat="item in column.items" class="card-item-height">
                                    <md-list-item class="md-3-line btn-draggable card-item" ng-class="{'card-item-margin': !$last}" ng-show="item.prospect_name" data-drag="{{item.drag}}" data-jqyoui-options="{revert: 'invalid'}" ng-model="column.items" jqyoui-draggable="{index: {{$index}}, animate:true}" id="draggable-item-{{$index}}" data-column-index="{{$parent.$index}}" data-column-index2="{{item}}">
```

The problem is that when i try to drag the cards outside of their containers, with the overflow-y auto property in the caption class, the cards can be dragged but they appear behind the other containers. This doesn´t happen if the property is not applied.

How to add the overflow-y auto property and make the draggable items work as expected.